# responsive layout only for medium and large using bootstrap3

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to create my web application responsive only for 2 type of displays.

```
For medium and smaller sized screens
For larger screens
```

Can I achieve this using bootstrap 3? I just want a fixed size container of 970px for all screens/devices having resolutions <= 1200px and for larger screens I want my container size 1170px

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at bootstrap's `container` class declaration in [`grid.less`](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/less/grid.less#L10)

```
.container {
  .container-fixed();

  @media (min-width: @screen-sm-min) {
    width: @container-sm;
  }
  @media (min-width: @screen-md-min) {
    width: @container-md;
  }
  @media (min-width: @screen-lg-min) {
    width: @container-lg;
  }
}
```

The code is self explanatory, you can make a custom built on their site.